# Get() and Set() between multiple @Test, Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian

I'm using Selenium WebDriver and Arquillian drone for these test.

how my tests are build :

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SimpleTest{

  private String idPo;

  public String getIdPo() {
    return idPo;
  }

  public void setIdPo(String id) {
    idPo = id;
  }

  @Test
  public void setTest() {
    setIdPo("5");
  }

  @Test
  public void getTest() {
    String temp = getIdPo(); // ----> returns null
    Assert.assertTrue(temp.equals("5"));
  }

}
```

When i set the value, everything seems to be ok, but when i switch to another test, `IdPo` is null. ***Is it possible that each `@Test` release and renew variables ?***

Comment: check which order the test cases are executing, if getTest() executes first its always null

Comment: if order is correct make idPo static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the error...

**When i call the getter i was using : `getId()` instead of `getIdPo()`.**

But Eclipse never underline `getId()` .. don't really know why.. because it doesn't exist in my code..

Answer (score 0):

I belive BeforeTest should help you.

> @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method
>   belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run.

Just write a method and annotate it with @BeforeTest and set the values as desired.